# How can I call a component in attribute of other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to call a component with route in another component but it doesn't work
could you help me please?

```
  <Route path="/products" >
                <RouterProduct
                    count={this.state.addCounter}
                    price={this.state.totalPrice}
                    close={
                        <Route path="/contact-us" component={RouterContact} />
                    } />
            </Route>
```

Comment: my problem is in this part:


  close={
                        <Route path="/contact-us" component={RouterContact} />
              } />

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass that `Route` element to `RouterProduct` component as a prop. Instead you should put `<Route path="/contact-us" component={RouterContact} />` inside `RouterProduct` component and also import `RouterContact` there.

Answer (score 0):

If `/products` and `/contact-us` are two top level routes and you want to navigate to `/contact-us` from within `/products` you can use `useHistory` hook to do so.

```
function App() {
  const history = useHistory();
  return
  <Router>
    <Route path="/products">
      <RouterProduct
        count={this.state.addCounter}
        price={this.state.totalPrice}
        close={() => history.push("/contact-us")}
      />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/contact-us" component={RouterContact} />
  </Router>;
}
```